# Thread with Laravel - Model class not found when calling start()

Tags: php, multithreading, laravel, pthreads

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I am trying to start several threads within a Command class:

```
$documents->chunk(1000, function($documentChunk) use (&$threads, &$threadNumber, &$repository) {
    $threads[$threadNumber] = new MyThread($documentChunk);
    $threads[$threadNumber]->start();
    $this->info("Thread [".$threadNumber."] running");
    $threadNumber++;
});
```

The **$documents** variable has been previously filled with some data retrieved from the database

In the MyThread class this is what I have:

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

use Download;

class MyThreadextends \Thread {

    protected $chunk;

    public function __construct($chunk) {
        $this->chunk = $chunk;
    }

    public function run() {
        ...
        $downloads = Download::select(...);
        ...
    }

}
```

On the select line, I get a:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Download' not found

However, if I call directly **$threads[$threadNumber]->run()** instead of **$threads[$threadNumber]->start()**, I do not have this error. Maybe it is a problem of class loading but I can't figure out what's the real problem and if it can be solved...

If someone could help me with this, I would be really grateful since it's been hours I'm on this problem.

Thanks,
Killian.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160037/4384751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a workaround. I don't use threads anymore but Guzzle. The code located in my thread is now in a controller method, accessible via an URL - I made a REST API. Guzzle allows me to do asynchronous requests, which is exactly what I wanted to do.

See [Guzzle documentation for Laravel](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your autoloader, [help here](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads-autoloading-composer)

I think the example is Symfony, but the same thing applies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I really don't see how to apply this example to my case...